# SubMenu disappear on hover on windows safari. Extjs

Tags: extjs

I am using below code of Extjs for menu. It works fine in chrome, IE and mozilla browser but the issue is only with safari on windows platform. The submenu disappear as soon as I try to hover over it.

```
var menuPanel=Ext.define('MenuPanel',{
extend:'Ext.menu.Menu',
alias:'widget',
width:100,
height:50,
items:[{
    text:'Menu 1',
    handler:function(){
        Ext.Msg.alert('Message','Clicked on Menu 1');

    }
     },
       {
           text:'Menu 2',
           handler:function(){
               Ext.Msg.alert('Message','Clicked on Menu 2');                   
           }
       }],
beforeShow:function(){
    var ownerCmp = Ext.getCmp(this.alignTarget.id);
    if (this.ownerCmp !== ownerCmp)
    { this.ownerCmp = ownerCmp; }
    this.callParent(arguments);
}

});
```

You can find the example of this on fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rv2. Please try opening this in safari of windows.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, Safari 5 is not a supported browser for Ext 6.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, I am using Ext 5.